# Best approaches to handle configuration change while using volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using asyntask to make network request in my apps. In that apps I use headless fragments to handle configuration change. Now I want to add Volley library in my next app, then what are the best approaches I need to follow to handle configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

To use Volley Library you can refer following link will helpful to you.

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/

Comment: its a simple volley example, what I want is how to handle configuration change while making a volley request  (ie : know the status of task running)